# Apache Beam Python - Parallelise multiple ReadFromBigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have to parallelise multiple ReadFromBigQuery inside my Beam pipeline.
One thing that could help is that **all the tables have the same structure** and will be put together. If you have a solution, please share it. I share with you what I tried in the past few days but no need to keep reading my struggle if you know the solution. Thank you very much!

1. If I try to simply execute them in a *for loop* (I tested with four tables but I will have many hundreds in production) and I run it into Dataflow, then it doesn't seem to scale at all: only one worker is activated (see image - the code which gave me this job is something like the one at the end of this post)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcCRM.png)
2. In the beginning, I tried to use Read**All**FromBigQuery but it sent me a warning saying that the function is experimental. I didn't bother about that at first, but when running on the whole bunch of tables, it seems to create duplicates (like if it was reading some tables twice and others only once). It's very unlikely this duplication comes from something else but I could be wrong.
3. I also tried with ParDo but my knowledges in Beam are too poor to understand how I should do it: it seems I cannot use a Read function from inside a `class MyClass(DoFn)` since it's not iterable. It's quite logic I think, but I couldn't find a better way.

**I think the last one should be the right solution but I cannot find answers on the internet. Can you help me? Thank you again, here some code used in the first two "solutions".**

The *for loop* I used is very simple, something like this:

```py
tables_list = [table1, table2, table3, table4]
query = 'SELECT id, value FROM `my-project.my-dataset.{table_name}`'

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    input_tables = [(
        p
        | 'Read {table}'.format(table = t) >> ReadFromBigQuery(
            query = query.format(table_name = t),
            use_standard_sql = True
        )
    ) for t in tables_list]
    final_table = (
        input_tables
        | 'Flatten in one table' >> beam.Flatten()
    )
```

The ReadAllFromBigQuery code was something like this. I am not sure if the duplication problem came from the ReadAll but it seems reasonable to me. Or at least from the to_bq_request function. I found this solution [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72006564/dynamic-query-to-apache-beam-io-gcp-bigquery-readfrombigquery) but maybe it isn't meant to work with hundreds of tables.

```py
tables_list = [table1, table2, table3, table4]
query = 'SELECT id, value FROM `my-project.my-dataset.{table_name}`'

def to_bq_request(t, query):
    from apache_beam.io import ReadFromBigQueryRequest
    return ReadFromBigQueryRequest(query = query.format(table_name = t))

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    pre_table = (
        p
        | 'Create Table' >> beam.Create(tables_list)
    )
    final_table = (
        pre_table
        | 'Map before ReadAll' >> beam.Map(to_bq_request, query = query)
        | 'Read All Tables ' >> ReadAllFromBigQuery(temp_dataset = 'tds')
    )
```

Comment: You have how many tables ? If the tables number is not high, I can propose you a more simpler solution.

Comment: Thanky you very much for answering. I have 400 tables and the pipeline has to be executed every day. Putting all the tables together will generate some billions of rows. But I will very gladly try your solution.

Comment: I believe only 1 may work. 2 never scales, since you have a single pipeline step which receives 400 different queries, while 3 requires writing a custom source ([splittable DoFn](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#splittable-dofns)) which is no easy task (only little to no docu for python available on the internet). I think your test with 1 did not scale, because the scaling wasn't triggered (see here for [batch](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#batch) or [streaming](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/horizontal-autoscaling#streaming)).

Comment: I think I understand it better now. Thank you @CaptainNabla Even though I'm not really sure you are right. I mean, I think n. 2 is scaling and it is scaling well. It is not scaling on the Create, on that I agree. I have to verify on the Map. But I'm pretty sure it scales well on the ReadAll. Does this make sense to you? I will come back tomorrow with some screenshot showing what I'm saying if it can helps. By the way thanks, I didn't know I could add some parameters to force the horizontal scale. It is a helpful advice!

Comment: I'm sorry to come back so soon @CaptainNabla but I read your link better and I don't think I have this problem. I mean, I'm doing a *batch* and if I understand it well the horizontal scaling is automatically active and I cannot do anything to force scaling on my solution N.1. I think there is something I'm not understanding. Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: In n1 you are reading from a table with a custom query. Beam/Dataflow does not know how to split this query. In this sense, it will never scale/execute a query in parallel. The only way it may scale, is by quering a lot of tables. Then different processes/workers query the different tables in parallel. I believe Dataflow didn't need a second worker to query your 4 tables at the same time, but if you increase the number of tables you query (e.g., try 50) it might work.

Comment: Ok @CaptainNabla I understand what you were saying. But of course I tried to run it on all my 400 tables before asking you. I don't remember what the error exactly said, but the terminal command wasn't able to start a job on Dataflow. I think it was something related to the memory. Maybe I should try with 50, just to see if it's scaling as you said. In that case maybe I could solve the problem in production, when I'm running my job from a custom template, right?

Comment: Im not sure, how using a template should affect memory issues during the pipeline run. If you run out of memory, you need more (or bigger) worker?

Comment: I had problems of memory saturation in the prerun, running the pipeline from my terminal. I tried with a template but it didn't work neither: when I try to create the template (using the for cycle solution), with 4 datasets it takes two minutes, with 20 datasets 10 minutes, 80 datasets 40 minutes. But with 400 datasets after 14 hours it hadn't finished yet, and it's clearly not acceptable to me. And strange too, I mean, the ratio seemed good. 200 minutes would have been fair. I'm waiting for a solution from Google engineers.